# Orthographie et orthographe

Tags: étymologie, orthographe

On peut assez facilement accéder à des sources montrant que le mot "orthographe" est une anomalie – bien sanctionnée par l'usage – pour qualifier l'art d'écrire correctement. Voir notamment [Littré 1872](https://www.littre.org/definition/orthographie) qui dénonce ce mot comme variante erronée d'**orthographie**.

Dans l'article orthographe, il pointe même : « *Le grec ὀρθογράφος signifie qui écrit bien ; de ὀρθὸς, droit, et γράφειν, écrire ; l'art d'écrire correctement se disait ὀρθογραφία, qui en français donne orthographie (voy. ce mot). C'est donc un usage bien fautif qui a dit orthographe, au lieu d'orthographie, surtout si l'on remarque que, dans tous les composés de γράφω, graphe signifie le savant, et graphie l'art : un géographe et la géographie, un hydrographe et l'hydrographie. Cette faute paraît appartenir au XVIe siècle.* »

Quelqu'un saurait-il trouver des circonstances et détails historiques (attestés) de cette bizarre substitution que nous continuons de perpétuer depuis cinq siècles ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

En 1539, l'ordonnance de Villers-Cotterêts impose le français<sup>1</sup> dans tous les documents officiels, en remplacement du latin que le peuple ne comprenait plus depuis longtemps. Nombreux sont les lettrés habitués à rédiger en latin qui ont dû se mettre au *langage maternel françoys*. L'orthographe du français n'est pas figée. Le besoin se fait sentir d'une réforme qui homogénéiserait l'écriture et clarifierait les règles de grammaire.

Plusieurs écoles s'affrontent au milieu du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle. Celle de [Louis Meigret](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Louis_Meigret) vise à simplifier l'orthographe en la mettant en conformité avec la prononciation, à l'image de ce que font les italiens, les espagnols et les allemands. Une autre, défendue en particulier par [Guillaume des Autels](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guillaume_Des_Autels), défend une écriture proche des racines latines.

Cette querelle et les arguments des uns et des autres est bien connue grâce à des ouvrages de l'époque.

[Jacques Peletier du Mans](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Peletier_du_Mans), ami de Ronsard et Joachim du Bellay ([la Pléiade](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%A9iade_(XVIe_si%C3%A8cle))) et qui prône une orthographe phonétique, écrit en 1547 :

[image]

> *Pour l'**orthographe**, ils entrent en colère
>
> comme pour chose indigne qu'on tolère,
>
> En alléguant l'usage pour l'abus
>
> Mais tout cela n'en vaut pas les tabust*   (troubles)
> *Je ne me veux, comme eux, rompre la tête
>
> La lettre laisse, et à l'esprit m'arrête.*

En 1550, il publie :

> *Dialogue  
> De l'**Ortografe** et prononciation Française, départi en deux livres par Jacques Peletier du Mans*

[image]

Le préambule de l'éditeur confronté à cette nouvelle forme d'écriture est instructif :

[image]

> Messieurs, vous devez, pour trois raisons, excuser aimablement les fautes qui se présenteront à vos yeux, en lisant une chose si ingénieusement inventée que ce présent traité. L'une est, l'absence de l'auteur. L'autre la nouveauté du sujet, tellement éloigné de notre commun usage d'écrire (louable néanmoins, pour beaucoup de causes que vous connaîtrez par le lecture de celui-ci) qu'il ne se faut point émerveiller, si ses préceptes mêmes ne sont gardés de tous points en lui, pour la première impression.

En 1550, Meigret publie *Défenses de Louis Meigret touchant son **orthographie** française, contre les censures et calomnies de Glaumalis de Vezelet<sup>2</sup>, et de ses adhérents*.

[image]

> *Comme j'achevais de revoir un traité que j'ai dressé cet hiver touchant la grammaire française, j'ai eu ces derniers jours nouvelles d'un traité intitulé «de l'Antique écriture de la langue française et de la poésie, contre l'orthographe des maigretistes ».*

Il écrit plus loin:

> *Venons meintenant ao demourant : je ne puis compręndre de qęll’ occazion tu as ajouté ao tiltre de ton euure, ę de la poesie contre l’orthographe des Meigretistes : car je ne puis ęntęndre c̨ete contrarieté : vu qe la poezíe trętte d’une fac̨on de parler par c̨erteines mezures de syllabes : ny ne trętte point de la fac̨on d’ecrire : attęndu q’on peut rymer sans ecritture : la ou l’art de bien ecrire qe nous pouuons appeller Orthographíe jit ęn la conoęssanc̨e dę’ caracteres ou lęttres, ę aotres figures, ę de leur puissanc̨’ ę proprieté pour pęrfęttemęnt rapporter l’imaje de la prononc̨íac̨íon : ny ne se męle de jujer si vne proze, ou ryme, ęt bien ordoné’ ę fętte selon lę’ regles du comun langaje, ou de la poęzíe.*

> Venons maintenant au demeurant. Je ne puis comprendre de quelle occasion tu as ajouté au titre de ton oeuvre, et de la poésie contre l'**orthographe** des Meigretistes, car je ne puis entendre cette contrariété vu que la poésie traite d'une façon de parler par certaines mesures de syllabes ni ne traite point de la façon d'écrire, attendu qu'on peut rimer sans écriture, là où l'art de bien écrire que nous pouvons appeler **Orthographie** git en la connaissance des caractères ou lettres, et autres figures, et de puissance et propriété pour parfaitement rapporter l'image de la prononciation, ni ne se mêle de juger si une prose, ou rime, est bien ordonnée et faite selon les règles du commun langage, ou de la poésie.

On voit que Meigret définit *orthographie* comme art de bien écrire tandis que ses adversaires utilisent *orthographe*.

Un an plus tard, pour soutenir l'idée que l'orthographe ne doit pas rester figée mais évoluer avec la prononciation, il écrit :

> *Parqoę qant a l’orthographie dę’ moz ę vocables c̨hacun deura la garder ęn son ecritture come de son tęns l’vzaje de la parolle le reqęrra. Lęssant ao demourant aos succ̨ęsseurs la męme libęrté de nouueao c̨hanjemęnt de leur prononc̨iac̨ion : dont nous auons vzé ęnuers l’antiqité : come l’esperianc̨e le nou’ montre.*

> Par quoi quant à l'**orthographie** des mots et vocables, chacun devra la garder en son écriture comme de son temps l'usage de la parole le requerra. Laissant au demeurant aux successeurs la même liberté de nouveaux changements de leur prononciation dont nous avons usé envers l'antiquité, comme l'expérience le nous montre.

Se plaignant du non respect de son orthographe par ses éditeurs, Meigret écrit en 1554 :

> Au demeurant, si le batiment de l’escripture vous semble autre et different de la doctrine qu’autrefoys je mis en avant, blamez en l’imprimeur, qui a préféré son gain à la raison : esperant le faire beaucoup plus grant et avoir plus prompt depeche de sa cacographie, que de mon orthographie.

On peut donc observer que le mot *orthographie* est utilisé par Meigret, moins régulièrement par ses partisans comme Jacques Peletier du Mans qui a pu écrire *ortografe*, mais que ses adversaires écrivaient eux *orthographe*.

C'est confirmé dans l'ouvrage « Art poetique francoys, pour l'instruction des jeunes studieux, & encor peu avancez en la poësie francoyse » de [Thomas Sébillet](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_S%C3%A9billet) et [Charles Fontaine](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Charles_Fontaine) où l'on trouve :

> Je passe cela que tu écris *Deffence* par double *f* et un *c*, à la manière des praticiens que tu appelles dépravateurs d'orthographe, au chapitre 7. du 2. et non *Defense* par simple *f* et *s*, selon sa vraie origine. **Car la paradoxe orthographie (qu'ils appellent *orthographe*)** [...] est tant vaine et incertaine que le procès est encore pendant, les uns suivant la raison, les autres l'usage, les autres l'abus, autres leur opinion et volonté.

Dans un ouvrage intitulé *Abrégé de l'art poétique français* (1565), Ronsard qui soutenait sans les avoir adoptées les idées de Meigret, on trouve un chapitre intitulé « Des personnes des verbes françois, et de l'**orthographie** » qui utilise l'ancienne forme.

Les éditions suivantes, posthumes, corrigent en *..., et de l'**orthographe***.

Au XVIII<sup>e</sup> siècle, le mot *orthographie* est répertorié avec le sens de dessin en projection orthogonale d'une oeuvre architecturale (élévation) :

[image: https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b7703140c.r=orthographe%20orthographie?rk=21459;2]

La plupart des terminaisons en -aphe désignent en français une personne pratiquant une technique en -aphie (calligraphe, cartographe, géographe, chorégraphe, photographe, dactylographe), parfois un objet (télégraphie, télégraphe) qui a donné télégraphiste.

Le verbe associé à orthographe est lui régulier : *orthographier*, pas *orthographer*. À l'image de télégraphiste, on trouve parfois *orthographiste*, par exemple dans le [Littré](https://www.littre.org/definition/orthographiste) (*Auteur qui écrit sur l'orthographe*)...

Paradoxalement, ce sont donc les partisans d'une écriture conservant l'héritage de ses racines qui semblent avoir introduit *orthographe*. On peut difficilement croire que c'était par méconnaissance de l'*orthographia* latine ou de l'*ὀρθογραφία* grecque.

Deux hypothèses sont possibles, une étymologie s'appuyant sur *ὀρθογράφος* (qui écrit bien), mais ce devrait être la personne, pas l'art, ou peut-être simplement un choix fait par réaction contre Meigret...

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Il ne s'agissait pas d'imposer le français mais de rejeter le latin qui n'était plus compris par la majorité des Français.</sub>
<sup>2</sup> <sub>Glaumalis de Vezelet est le pseudonyme (et l'anagramme) de Guillaume des Autels</sub>

Sources:

- [Défenses de Louis Meigret touchant son **orthographie** française, contre les censures et calomnies de Glaumalis de Vezelet<sup>1</sup>, et de ses adhérents](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b8610760h)
- [Pierre Ramus et André Wechel : un libraire au service d’un auteur](https://books.openedition.org/enc/546?lang=fr)
- [Corpus d’écrits phonétiques du XVI<sup>e</sup> siècle](https://virga.org/phon16/index.php?item=1)
- [Les oeuvres poétiques de Jacques Peletier du Mans](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k54497891.image)
- [Art poetique francoys, pour l'instruction des jeunes studieux, & encor peu avancez en la poësie francoyse](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k9800821p)
- [La rhétorique de la polémique dans la Réplique aux furieuses défenses de Louis Meigret de Guillaume des Autels](https://www.persee.fr/doc/rhren_1771-1347_2014_num_78_1_3365)
- [Orthographie : côté de l'entrée d'une maison de campagne appellée le temple du Silence](https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/btv1b7703140c.r=orthographe%20orthographie?rk=21459;2)

Comment: Un immense merci jliagre pour un tel déploiement d'éléments dont plusieurs sont pour moi de vraies découvertes. Je vais lire cela à tête reposée mais il y a déjà des citations très pertinentes. Encore bravo !

Comment: J'ai moi aussi beaucoup découvert dans cette recherche qui m'a fait lire des trucs passionnants.  Dire que nous aurions pu avoir une *orthographie* régulière, comme la plupart de nos voisins (sauf les anglais bien sûr)... Quel dommage !

Comment: J'ai retiré une virgule qui ne se trouvait pas dans l’édition, et dont même le lecteur moderne peut se passer. En outre, j'ai substitué *causes* à *choses*, mais ne suis pas certains s'il y avait eu un choix délibéré de votre part en ce cas particulier. Si *causes* vous semble inapproprié ou inélégant, on pourrait penser à *raisons*, plus près en esprit, si pas phonétiquement. Et chapeau pour la très belle recherche (je n'avais pas encore eu la chance d'avoir qqch d'utile à mentionner en commentaire).

Comment: @Montéedelait C'était bien *causes*, une coquille de ma part. Merci !